# Finding the maximum real part of roots

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, complex

Suppose that I have this problem

```
roots = 
  Reduce[
    Sin[z + Sin[z + Sin[z]]] == Cos[z + Cos[z + Cos[z]]] && 
    -3 < Re[z] < 3 && -3 < Im[z] < 3, z] // Quiet;   

ListPlot[{Re[z], Im[z]} /. {ToRules[roots]}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
    Style[TraditionalForm[Sin[z + Sin[z + Sin[z]]] == Cos[z + Cos[z + Cos[z]]]], 14],  
  PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Thus as in https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/newin7/content/TranscendentalRoots/PlotTheRootsOfANestedTranscendentalEquation.html
I get a beautiful solution. Suppose now that this equation depends on quantity `a` in a range of (1, 2).

```
roots[a_] := 
  Reduce[
    Sin[z + Sin[z + Sin[z]]] == a + a Cos[z + a Cos[z + Cos[z]]] && 
    -3 < Re[z] < 3 && -3 < Im[z] < 3, z] // Quiet;  `
```

But I don't want the real and imaginary part for each vale of a specified `a`, rather I would like to have a plot that is a continuous function of `a`, and the maximum of the real part of the `z`.

Is there any way to do it?

I have tried this,

```
Plot[Max[Re[z]] /. {ToRules[roots[a_]]}, {a, 1, 2}, 
  PlotLabel -> PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

but it has been running for a day and I still have not got any result.

Comment: Try discretizing the `a` value in the relevant range. If you assume the result to be smooth, you'll get a good approximation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use a numeric technique, i.e., [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html).

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := 
 Max@Re[z /. 
    NSolve[Sin[z + Sin[z + Sin[z]]] == 
       a + Cos[z + a*Cos[z + a*Cos[z]]] && -3 < Re[z] < 3 && 
       -3 < Im[z] < 3 && 1 <= a <= 2, z]]
```

Since `f` uses a numeric technique, its argument is restricted to numeric values by using [`PatternTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) with [`NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html). Even using numeric techniques the calculations are slow.

```
AbsoluteTiming[data = Table[{a, f[a]}, {a, 1, 2, .025}];]

(* {803.729, Null} *)

ListLinePlot[data,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel ->
  (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {"a", "Max[Re[z]]"})]
```

[image]

The plot is not smooth so if you were to use [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) its adaptive sampling would further increase the time required.

Comment: It took longer for me (2673.97 seconds), but it work! Thank you so much for your clever answer!